# execute a Linux command on a EC2 instance using Jmeter ssh sampler

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I’m trying to execute a Linux command from my local windows server to remote EC2 instance using Jmeter ssh sampler plug in ,what is the way to connect to ec2 with my private key file and send the command?

Answer (score 2):

Follow next simple steps:

1. From [JMeter SSH Sampler Releases page](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler/releases):

   - Download latest version of `ApacheJMeter_ssh-x.x.x.jar` and drop it to /lib/ext folder of your JMeter installation
   - Download `jsch-x.x.x.jar` and drop it to /lib folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter to pick the jars up
3. Add `SSH Command` Sampler to your Test Plan - there will be "Client certificate" input section where you can specify private key and password if needed

   [image: JMeter SSH Sampler]

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) guide for more detailed information on the topic.

Comment: I don't have this option in my jmeter

Comment: i have only user and password option in ssh command i dont have the option of Client certification values,why?

Comment: Maybe you have different plugin installed. Try out clean JMeter and plugin installation